# Not able to ping router's WAN IP from a machine on LAN network

Tags: ubuntu, routing, iptables

I have a machine (Linux ubuntu) that acts as a router, the routing is working fine.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
```

A machine on `eth0` network can ping another machine on `wg0` network using this router.

What I can't do is: from a machine on `eth0` ping the `wg0`-ip of the router.

To make it clear:

`[Machine A: IP 192.168.68.2]` <--> `[Router eth0: 192.168.68.114 / wg0: 10.100.100.2]` <--> `[Machine B: 10.100.100.1]`

`Machine A` can ping: `192.168.68.114` and `10.100.100.1` but **not** `10.100.100.2`

When I'm pinging `10.100.100.2` from `Machine A`, I'm able to see the ping incoming-packages in the `Router` using `tcpdump` on it, but, it is being discarded before reach `iptables`, the counter, in the chain level, is not increasing.

As I understood so far the `Router` is discarding the packages, but I wasn't able to find where.

Any idea of how to make the `Router`'s Wan IP available within the LAN?

Comment: That will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/)

Comment: I will take a look into that, thanks. Considering that the router is a linux box, any hint of how to do it?

PS: for me the main tricky thing is that I can see the package on tcpdump, but not in iptables, so there is no rule that would apply for it.

Comment: Sorry, no......

Comment: I found the problem, wireguard, add a DROP rule that is causing the problem. I didn't notice the counter increasing in this particular rule, and becuase of that I haven't noticed the problem. - I will reply soon with details. Thanks

Comment: Great. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the described error is: there was an `iptables` rule (on raw/PREROUTING) that was dropping packets. Once I removed that, everything was working as expected.

About my problem itself, the `wg0` interface is being created by Wireguard tool `wg-quick`, which adds the rules by default.

To solve this, I added a rule using the interface configuration file:

`PostUp = iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i eth0 --src 192.168.68.0/24 --dst 10.100.100.2 -j ACCEPT`